# Set Variable as Name of JLabel

Tags: java, swing, loops

I'm trying to create JLabels in a loop and remove them at the End. So I need to give every Label its own name (Like Label[1], Label[2],...). I'm very new to Java so I can't imagine how to solve this problem. I already tried different ways but they all didn't work.

Comment: *"I'm very new to Java so I can't imagine how to solve this problem."* Use the `String` name of the `JLabel` as a key in a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). As an aside, it is a good idea to get used to classes and methods, control structures, data types & **data structures** in simple command line based apps. Adding a GUI adds an entire extra layer of complications..

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but you can add a number of anonymous objects(in this case they will be `JLabel` or `Label`) to the `Array List` without naming them.(You need to use for loops). If you want to delete them, you need to use the same logic.

Let me know this works or not. If you stuck again, I can help you by writing the code. However, writing yourself will be more beneficial for you.

Have a nice day !!

Comment: *"I can help you by writing the code."* Not here, you can't. SO is a Q&A site, not a code generation machine.